# Checking a mathematical statement with sampling method?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose we have a mathematical statement P(x) related to a real number x in (a,b)
And we have a method to determine the correctness of P(x) for any x in (a,b)
If we randomly select x for finite times, and suppose all P(x) is true for choosen x. 
What we can say about the correctness of P(x)in(a,b) in perspective of sampling?
Does it have a concrete theoretical foundation of similar problem?

Comment: You can say nothing. Consider you have a function that takes value 0 in the interval [-N,N] and 1 elsewhere where N is mind bogglingly large . Then with ur sampling method you will with high enough probability deduce that your function is identically 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, since you can not test all possible outcomes. Depending on the exact hypothesis on $P$, you can get both false-positive and false-negative answers. The "hypothesis testing" part of statistics has various tools that estimate, e.g. "the probability to reject a valid hypothesis" or "if my hypothesis is true, what is the probability of the observed outcome of my tests". An article on [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) can be a good start.